# Running private monero mainnet

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

How can I run my own monero ecosystem? I want to have my own blockchain (private Mainnet = Fresh blockchain) , defferent with monero blockchain

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a private testnet according to [these instructions](https://github.com/moneroexamples/private-testnet)

Change the folder names according to your preference, and remove the --testnet flag to use mainnet network parameters.

Comment: Correct. More specifically, a private network (whether testnet, stagenet or mainnet) uses the `--add-exclusive-node` option on the nodes. That's what makes it private.

Comment: is there  --mainnet flag? How can I rebrand and create my own currency?

Comment: Just remove --testnet and it will default to mainnet. Your other questions are out of scope, as well as huge challenging technical undertakings. Why not reach out to us on IRC to work on some Monero issues to get to know the currency and community :)